# Displaying marginal effects using avg_slopes() for Specific Level Transitions in plm Models with Interaction Terms

Tags: r, hypothesis-test, marginal-effects, modelsummary, r-marginaleffects

I am analyzing panel data using the plm package in R and have run into a challenge with interpreting and calculating the output from the `avg_slopes` function. My model looks at life_satisfaction as a function of employment_level (with three categories: non_working, part_time, full_time), interaction with current_children(one_child, two_children, more_than_two_children), and other control variables.

Here's a simplified representation of my model:

```r
mod_2 <- plm(life_satisfaction ~ employment_level * current_children + ...,
             data = data_analyse_mother, 
             index = c("pid", "syear"), 
             model = "within")`
```

I'm using `avg_slopes()` to understand the marginal effects of shifting between employment levels, particularly when changing from non_working to full_time, and from part_time to full_time, and from part_time to non-working across different levels of current_children.

Here's the avg_slopes call:

```r
avg <- avg_slopes(mod_2, variables = "employment_level", by="current_children")
```

The output provides contrasts between non_working and full_time, as well as part_time and full_time, but it does not directly show the contrast from non_working to part_time. Below is a replicated table of the output:

```r
| term             | contrast                               | current_children         | estimate    |
|------------------|----------------------------------------|--------------------------|-------------|
| employment_level | mean(Not_Working) - mean(Full_Time)    | more_than_two_children   | -0.33049722 |
| employment_level | mean(Not_Working) - mean(Full_Time)    | one_child                | -0.21408351 |
| employment_level | mean(Not_Working) - mean(Full_Time)    | two_children             | -0.25985500 |
| employment_level | mean(Part_Time) - mean(Full_Time)      | more_than_two_children   | -0.22848561 |
| employment_level | mean(Part_Time) - mean(Full_Time)      | one_child                | -0.09376425 |
| employment_level | mean(Part_Time) - mean(Full_Time)      | two_children             | -0.06093251 |
```

I need to compare the effect of transitioning from non_working to part_time. What is the appropriate approach to obtain this specific contrast using avg_slopes.

I tried the pairwise hypothesis, but it didn`t work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default is to compare all levels to the baseline category (the first observed category or the "reference" level of a factor). You can change this by using the `avg_comparisons()` function and its `variables` argument:

```r
avg <- avg_comparisons(mod_2, 
  variables = list("employment_level" = "pairwise"), 
  by = "current_children")
```

Note that `avg_slopes()` is just a thin wrapper around `avg_comparisons()`, which specifies `comparison="dydx"` for numeric variables. The results should be the same.

Please read the `comparisons()` function documentation for more details: https://marginaleffects.com/man/comparisons.html#arguments

Comment: Dear Vincent, one more question, how can I plot this? ` plot_comparisons(mod_2_fe, variables = "employment_level", condition = "current_children_under_17_category")`
Fehler: Unable to compute predicted values with this model. This error can arise when `insight::get_data()` is unable to extract the dataset from the model object, or when the data frame was modified since
  fitting the model. You can try to supply a different dataset to the `newdata` argument.
  
  In addition, this error message was raised:
  
  Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]):

Comment: Please read the documentation for the `variables` argument and see the examples on the website.